# Spark SqlContext output JSON format

Tags: java, json, postgresql, apache-spark

I have retrieved data from postgres Database using Spark SqlContext.

Here is the sample code:

```
        Class.forName(dbDriver);

        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
        options.put("url", dbUrl);
        options.put("dbtable", dbTable);
        options.put("driver", dbDriver);

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JAVA_SPARK")
                .setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.ui.port‌​", "7077");

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(jsc);

        DataFrame dframe = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc")
                .options(options).load();

        dframe.show();
```

I have got the following output:

```
+------+---+
|  name|age|
+------+---+
|abc   | 20|
|xyz   |  4|
+------+---+
```

I want the output to be in JSON format.Is there any way to convert this format to JSON or other specific way than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert the DF to json then you can use following.

```
JavaRDD<String> jsonRDD = dframe.toJSON().toJavaRDD();      
jsonRDD.foreach(data -> {
        System.out.println(data);
    });
```

If you want to save it as json file then use

```
dframe.write().json("c:\\temp\\myfile.json");
```

If you want to get it as List then call take() or collect(). Please refer Spark doc for when to use these methods.

```
List<String> mylist = jsonRDD.collect();
```

Comment: Thanks It worked.But how to get output in this format {"name":"abc","age":"20"} is there any way for achieving this.

Comment: What do you want to do with DF? Do you want to save this DF in json file?

Comment: I want to pass the retrieved data from the table using DF to the front end in JSON format.

Comment: In Spark output will be RDD or DF type. You can save it as file or store it in database. You can also populate java beans from the RDD or DF  and use that java bean in your program. Please refer Spark documentation for more details.  I have edited my answer above.